# How identify a Virtual Hard Disk how unique in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, hdparm, serial-number

I'm get the Hard Disk serial number with "hdparm, sdparm, /sbin/udevadm and lshw" is possible in a physical drive, but when i use the "Hyper-V" i don't have the serial number. 
How i can get the serial number from hard disk in this environment of virtualization or any other number to identify the hard disk how unique?

My tries:

sdparm -li /dev/sda

```
   /dev/sda: Msft      Virtual Disk      1.0
Device identification [0x83] VPD page:
  Addressed logical unit:
    designator type: T10 vendor identification,  code set: Binary
      vendor id: MSFT
      vendor specific: ▒▒▒H▒F▒▒"?▒LQ▒
    designator type: NAA,  code set: Binary
      NAA 6, IEEE Company_id: 0x2248
      Vendor Specific Identifier: 0x83119188
      Vendor Specific Identifier Extension: 0x4897223f824c51fe
      [0x60022480831191884897223f824c51fe]
```

hdparm -i /dev/sda

```
/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument
```

hdparm -I /dev/sda

```
/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
        Likely used: 1
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   0       0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY not likely
        Cannot perform double-word IO
        R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: pio0
```

/sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name=sda

```
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360022480831191884897223f824c51fe /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x60022480831191884897223f824c51fe /dev/disk/by-path/acpi-VMBUS:00-scsi-0:0:0:0
DEVNAME=/dev/sda
DEVPATH=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/device:07/VMBUS:00/vmbus_0_1/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda
DEVTYPE=disk
ID_BUS=scsi
ID_MODEL=Virtual_Disk
ID_MODEL_ENC=Virtual\x20Disk\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PATH=acpi-VMBUS:00-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=acpi-VMBUS_00-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=1.0
ID_SCSI=1
ID_SERIAL=360022480831191884897223f824c51fe
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=60022480831191884897223f824c51fe
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_VENDOR=Msft
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Msft\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_WWN=0x6002248083119188
ID_WWN_VENDOR_EXTENSION=0x4897223f824c51fe
ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x60022480831191884897223f824c51fe
MAJOR=8
MINOR=0
SUBSYSTEM=block
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=90937344
```

lshw -class disk

```
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD reader
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       capabilities: audio dvd
       configuration: status=nodisc
  *-disk
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       size: 8GiB (8589MB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=00077a0d
```

Some have returned many data ('/sbin/udevadm and lshw'), but not know if i can use to identify how unique, even the number that changes every formatting me would be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

These two should be enough to identify the same disk, even usually in virtualized environment.

```
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360022480831191884897223f824c51fe /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x60022480831191884897223f824c51fe
```